# Elastic net penalty

Tags: ridge-regression, glmnet, elastic-net

I have a question about the elastic net penalty as implemented in `glmnet` in R compared to the original paper by Zou and Hastie (2005). In `glmnet` the penalty is listed as

$$
(1-\alpha)/2||\beta||_2^2+α||\beta||_1.
$$

but in the paper it is

$$(1-\alpha)||\beta||_1 + \alpha||\beta||_2^2. 
$$

Does anyone know where the factor $\frac12$ some from? (Never mind the fact that the $\alpha$'s were swapped between the two parameterisations.) In both cases the penalties are multiplied by $\lambda$, but what are the mathematical/technical arguments for not using a simple convex combination of the lasso and ridge penalties?

Comment: There's definitely no mathematical argument, because the first formulation can be converted to the second simply by a change of units of measure for the betas (which amounts to a change in how the columns of the design matrix are standardized).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of these *are* simple convex combinations of lasso and ridge penalities, only the meaning of *ridge penalty* is slightly different in each.

In the first, the ridge penalty term is taken to be

$$ \frac{1}{2} \left| \beta \right|_2^2 $$

and in the second the ridge penalty is taken to be

$$ \left| \beta \right|_2^2 $$

The way its written as $ \frac{\alpha - 1}{2} \left| \beta \right|_2^2 $ is, unfortunately, a little confusing.  You should think of the $\frac{1}{2}$ as being part of the penalty and not part of the convex combination.

As for why the $\frac{1}{2}$ at all?  In certain calculations (for example, when deriving the update step in `glmnet`) you need to take a gradient with respect to $\beta$.  The $\frac{1}{2}$ is mathematically convenient to have, as it cancels with the exponent of $2$ after differentiation.  Since it doesn't hurt anything conceptually to include the $\frac{1}{2}$, many people do.

Comment: Ah that makes sense - I just couldn't figure out why it was a good idea to specify it explicitly. Thanks to both you and @whuber